# i want, with autohotkey, get current time in milliseconds since midnight

Tags: autohotkey

i want get current time in milliseconds since midnight.

I do not know if this is possible at all?

I know **A_TickCount** gives number of milliseconds since the computer was rebooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current time in milliseconds, you can use the Winapi functions GetSystemTime (UTC date) or GetLocalTime (local date).

```
;get current time in milliseconds (since midnight)
vDate := RegExReplace(A_Now, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
vDateUTC := RegExReplace(A_NowUTC, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
vMSec := JEE_TimeNowMSec()
vMSecUTC := JEE_TimeNowMSec("UTC")
vOutput1 := vDate "`r`n" vMSec "`r`n" (vMSec/86400000)
vOutput2 := vDateUTC "`r`n" vMSecUTC "`r`n" (vMSecUTC/86400000)
MsgBox, % vOutput1 "`r`n`r`n" vOutput2

JEE_TimeNowMSec(vOpt:="")
{
    VarSetCapacity(SYSTEMTIME, 16, 0)
    if (vOpt = "UTC")
        DllCall("kernel32\GetSystemTime", Ptr,&SYSTEMTIME)
    else
        DllCall("kernel32\GetLocalTime", Ptr,&SYSTEMTIME)
    vHour := NumGet(&SYSTEMTIME, 8, "UShort") ;wHour
    vMin := NumGet(&SYSTEMTIME, 10, "UShort") ;wMinute
    vSec := NumGet(&SYSTEMTIME, 12, "UShort") ;wSecond
    vMSec := NumGet(&SYSTEMTIME, 14, "UShort") ;wMilliseconds
    return vHour*3600000 + vMin*60000 + vSec*1000 + vMSec
}
```

To instead get the current time in seconds, you can parse the built-in variables A_Now/A_NowUTC, or use FormatTime.

```
;get current time in seconds (since midnight)
vDate := RegExReplace(A_Now, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
vDateUTC := RegExReplace(A_NowUTC, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
oDate := StrSplit(vDate, " ")
oDateUTC := StrSplit(vDateUTC, " ")
vSec := oDate.4*3600 + oDate.5*60 + oDate.6
vSecUTC := oDateUTC.4*3600 + oDateUTC.5*60 + oDateUTC.6
vOutput1 := vDate "`r`n" vSec "`r`n" (vSec/86400)
vOutput2 := vDateUTC "`r`n" vSecUTC "`r`n" (vSecUTC/86400)
MsgBox, % vOutput1 "`r`n`r`n" vOutput2
return

;get current time in seconds (since midnight)
vDate := RegExReplace(A_Now, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
vDateUTC := RegExReplace(A_NowUTC, "(?<=..)..(?=.)", "$0 ")
FormatTime, vDateTemp,, HH:mm:ss
FormatTime, vDateTempUTC, % A_NowUTC, HH:mm:ss
oTime := StrSplit(vDateTemp, ":")
oTimeUTC := StrSplit(vDateTempUTC, ":")
vSec := oTime.1*3600 + oTime.2*60 + oTime.3
vSecUTC := oTimeUTC.1*3600 + oTimeUTC.2*60 + oTimeUTC.3
vOutput1 := vDate "`r`n" vSec "`r`n" (vSec/86400)
vOutput2 := vDateUTC "`r`n" vSecUTC "`r`n" (vSecUTC/86400)
MsgBox, % vOutput1 "`r`n`r`n" vOutput2
return
```

Comment: interesting. vOutput1 != vOutput2.https://gist.github.com/sl5net/e956bce4c499913ad5d0187f43639297

Comment: This is re. local time v. UTC time. Notice the difference in hours.

Comment: milli diff is nearly nothing at my measurement = 0.083333

Comment: The number at the bottom is the fraction of the day elapsed. Used to check if the results are plausible e.g. 16:00 would be 0.66...

Comment: You can retrieve the milliseconds value directly by editing the function.

Comment: yes. thats great. thanks. Which version I take is probably completely no matter(?)

Comment: If you want the 'milliseconds since the last second' (similar to AutoHotkey's built-in A_MSec variable), it probably doesn't matter whether you use GetSystemTime or GetLocalTime. Although I don't know for definite that these will always match for any time zone. (Otherwise for 'milliseconds since midnight' (local v. UTC), that depends on what you're using that number for.)

Answer (score 6):

See [DateTime](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#date)
Milliseconds can be calculated from current time like this:

```
F1::
    millis := (a_hour*3600 + a_min*60 + a_sec)*1000 + a_msec
    tooltip %millis%
return
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this should be the correct answer.